# Use Javascript/Jquery to iterate through table rows and checkboxes and add attribute of checkbox to array if checked

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, html-table

I have a PHP page with 5 checkboxes in each table row, I have some Javascript code that iterates through all the checkboxes to determine if their value has changed from what was originally grabbed from the database, and if the checkbox value has changed it is assigned the attribute changed='true'. What I am trying to do now is go through every single row of my table and if the checkbox is checked and its attr changed='true' then I want to put it it's attribute "checkboxtype" in my array, which should show in console. My array should also be dumped when my function moves on to a new table row. I have the following code, but it doesn't work as is...

```
    $('#myTable1 tr').each(function(){
        myArray = [];                  //dump array

    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    boxes.each(function() {   //function iterates through each input type of checkbox, it is defined in some earlier code
        if(this.checked && $(this).data("changed") == 'yes'){
        myArray.push($(this).attr('checkboxtype'));
        console.log(myArray);
        }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: It's worth noting that posting your representative [minimum, complete, verified example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) HTML, and a specimen of the expected output, would probably lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems complicated, a better jQuery selector will take care of most of it.

```
myArray = [];

$('#myTable1 input:checked[data-changed=yes]')
   .each(function() { 
        myArray.push($(this).attr('checkboxtype')); 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest:

```
// selects the checkbox inputs:
var myArray = $('#myTable1 tr td input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function(){
    // retains only those whose checked state has been changed:
    return this.checked == this.defaultChecked;
// moves to the first td ancestor of those changed checkboxes:
}).closest('td').map(function() {
    // pushes the content of the checkboxtype attribute to the map:
    return this.getAttribute('checkboxtype');
// creates/forms the array:
}).get();
```

Though rather than creating your own, invalid, attributes I'd further suggest using HTML 5's (valid) custom `data-*` attributes, to give an attribute such as `data-checkboxtype` and the jQuery:

```
var myArray = $('#myTable1 tr td input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function(){
    return this.checked == this.defaultChecked;
}).closest('td').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('checkboxtype');
}).get();
```

References:

- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).